# Why does "but" comes after "save"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I took the following extract from the link ;
http://www.viewzone.com/aging.html

The title was : Can science make us immortal?

“From every tree in the garden did he grant them to eat, ***save but one***. And that tree, in the center of the garden, was called the tree of life. And the Snake said to Eve, "Eat of this fruit and you will become as God and never die.-- Genesis 3:1”

I have a doubt regarding the part labeled above, in *bold* and *Italic*. **Save one**, at here means, *eat from all the trees except one tree.*

But both of the words *save* and *but* means *except*. So why does *except* came two times in the above context?

Comment: `save but one` means `except one`. Sometimes `but` can be used as `except`, but often not the other way around

Comment: I read this *but* as *just*: *save **just** this one*, i.e. *except only this one*.

Answer (score 5):

It is – at least to the modern reader – redundant. Actually, these two sentences would mean exactly the same:

> You can eat all fruits, except one.
>   You can eat all fruits save one.
>   You can eat all fruits but one.

The text you are quoting is from the Bible, and it is not uncommon to find sentences in the translations that may seem a bit overwrought. 
The first major translation (the King James Version) is often quoted (I don't think this is a KJV quite) and seems archaic to modern readers. Interestingly, it actually introduced a lot of new words and phrases into the English language and was certainly not seen as particularly overwrought at the time it was written.

In general, when people translate or quite texts that are considered sacred, they tend to use quite (or even extremely) formal language. In this case, to emphasize that there was one, and one only, fruit that was forbidden, both *save* and *but* are used.

Don't break your head over it too much, just in general, do not adopt biblical style English in your everyday speech :)

Comment: Thou hast answered well :^) Still, I have one question, and one comment. Comment: I don't think the excerpt here is a quote from a Genesis, but one writer's [paraphrase](https://www.google.com/#q=%22in+the+center+of+the+garden+was+called+the+tree+of+life%22) of the account. (Still, I think your answer is accurate, because I believe that author is trying to make it _sound_ like a Scriptural quote.) Question: Is there a reason you put a comma in the first example sentence before _except_, but omitted the comma before _save_? (I agree there should be no comma before _but_.)

Comment: Thank you :) I was afraid that question would come. Writing the three sentences, I realised I put a comma before _except_, and no comma before _but_. At that moment, somehow, no comma before _save_ looked and sounded better. I can't say I am 100% sure whether there should be one or not.

Comment: I can accept that it's a grey area; a judgement call. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

We can paraphrase ***save but one*** as ***except only one***.  In either case, the second word is unnecessary, and stylistically some might consider it undesirable.  But in either case, we can interpret it as an emphatic form, expressing the same idea but more forcefully.

This phrasing is rare, however.  It's more common to write simply ***save one***, as you might expect.  I searched the [*Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)*](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/) for the following strings:

```
  save one .          24 results - 4 false positives = 20 results
  save but one        0 results
```

So although we can try to explain the phrase you're asking about, it's a rather unusual way to say it.  Of course, in everyday speech ***except one*** and ***but one*** are even more common:

```
  but one .           110 results
  except one .        74 results
```

But these don't have quite the same formal tone that ***save one*** or ***save but one*** does.

As an aside, many translations of the bible use archaic or poetic sounding language, and the text you quote here is written in the same style.  Although you may be interested in *understanding* these sentences, you may want to avoid imitating them in your own speech!

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment, this doesn't appear to be a Biblical excerpt. (I think it's a conglomeration from Genesis meant to look like a Scriptural quote.)

Comment: @J.R. Oh, thanks for pointing that out.  I saw the "Genesis 3:1" cite and just assumed that it was a translation.